# Decoding Scrambed Binary Data from GPS with Python

Tags: python, binary, gps

I've got a raw binary file ([1 KB](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1355055/20160128t184727_pps?dl=1)↓) that is a serial data dump of a GPS stream (along with some associated metadata).  I'm specifically trying to pull a value out of the binary file that represents the GPS time; I know its offset and width in the file (10 and 8 bytes respectively, with a total frame width of 28 bytes) but it's encoded in a very weird way as described in the quote below.

What's the most Pythonic way to read this data (into a list or array)?

---

> GPS TIME - GPS Sensor time (time of week in seconds, starting at
>   Saturday 2400 hours/ Sunday 0000 hours) if GPS Time Valid Message 3500
>   is set to 1, otherwise SDN500 system time since power up is reported.
>   Data words are in the order 2, 1 (MSW), 4 (LSW), 3.

---

> A message word length is 16 bits on the SDN500–HV interface. However,
>   the SDN500–HV protocol, which uses a standard *Universal Asynchronous
>   Receiver Transmitter* (UART), transmits data in 8-bit groups (bytes).
>   This means that two bytes are required in order to make up one message
>   word.
>
> A byte of information is transmitted as a sequence of 11 bits: one
>   start bit, 8 bits of data (least significant bit (LSB) first), one
>   parity bit (odd), and one stop bit. For each 16-bit data word, the
>   least significant byte is transmitted first, followed by the most
>   significant byte. Integer and floating point data types consisting of
>   more than one word are transmitted from the lowest numbered word to
>   the highest numbered word. The one exception to this rule is the time
>   tag, which is output in words 6-9 of each HV output message. The four
>   16-bit data words are in the following order: 2,1,4,3, where 1
>   represents the most significant word and 4 the least significant word.
>   Each word is separately byte-reversed.

Comment: If you're more proficient in another language (like Matlab or C), I'd still love to see an example snippet of code that would read this data.  This would help me understand how to better approach reading it in Python.

Comment: Hopefully someone else will give you better info, but the https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html module is where you want to start looking for binary file i/o.  I only used it once for a short while, so can't help much more.

Comment: @JLPeyret yeah I've been messing with struct.unpack variations and a hex editor all day trying to get reasonable values out of this but haven't figured out the right way to read the MSB/LSB structure.  Though I was able to read some of the other fields that way.

Comment: what gps device are you using?

Comment: @JoranBeasley It's a SDN500

Answer (score 2, accepted):

start by opening the file

```
fin = open("20160128t184727_pps","rb")
```

then read in a frame

```
def read_frame(f_handle):
    frame = f_handle.read(28) # 28 byte frame size
    start_byte = 10
    end_byte = 18 # 4 words each word is 2 bytes
    timestamp_raw = frame[start_byte:end_byte]
    timestamp_words = struct.unpack(">HHHH",timestamp_raw)
```

I could probably help more but I dont understand where the timestamp startbyte and endbyte is from your description as it does not seem to match the description you quoted ... I also do not know what the expected output value is ...if you provided those details I could probably help more

Comment: Thanks.  I edited the question a few min ago as I had the wrong width.  I'll give your approach a shot.

Comment: oh ok I see now it sounds more realistic ... combining them back im not sure what you are expecting ? somehting like `20160322134566` (YMDHMS)? or a timestamp of seconds since the epoch? or ?

Comment: The GPS is reporting time since the start of the week (starting with Sunday).  I think it's in seconds.

Comment: that is a strange way to report timestamps ... are you sure about that? theres no way that should take 8 bytes ... if you want to email me the pdf that explains their messages I would take a look for you ... my email is just my first and last name at gmail.com

Comment: Time since start of week is how GPS time is represented normally AFAIK, at least that's how I've worked with it before.  The tricky part is the wonky ordering of MSW/LSW and I have no idea why it's set up that way.  The quotes in my question are literally copied/pasted out of the user manual.

Comment: oh I see ... thats really strange I have worked with some GPS recievers but they always end up with timestamps that look like my YMDHMS example ... hmmm ill look at it some more ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107289/discussion-between-nickv2002-and-joran-beasley).

Comment: I got everything working eventually. Thanks again for your help. The real problem was that the data was scrambled in a very poorly documented way.  Once I got a source code example (unfortunately export-controlled) I was able to decode properly without much trouble.  Giving you answer credit anyway for all the help. Thanks